# Slider jquery UI not appearing on my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing my jquery skills and want to use the slider found in the jquery ui [over here.](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) I have tried implementing this on my code but the slider does not appear. All that appears is 'Rpice Range: $75- $300'. I have tried making sure I have the right jquery version. This is my code. Nothing too complex, just my trying to test out the slider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.js">

<style>
div{
padding-right: 30%;
padding-left: 30%;
}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div> <h1>Resorts 'R' Us</h1>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked at the console window when my chrome browser was running it but there was no error. So why is this not displaying? Also another question, would I be able to use bootstrap with all the jquery uis?

Comment: This `<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.js">` is wrong

Comment: I just changed it to <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" and it does not show up. I do have another file similar to this which contains bootstrap and it works on there..

Comment: What you posted works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gbgok38u/

Comment: replace <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" > with <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" > . it appears your path is not correct for jquery-ui.css